# Cannot find method sendEmail(object)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

While trying to write a script on Google Sheets, I'm getting an error:

> Cannot find method sendEmail(object)

for the following code. As you can understand, it's an introduction email to a new client, presenting to the client his account rep.

```
  var clientname = spreadsheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
  var clientemail = spreadsheet.getRange('P2').getValue();
  var repname = spreadsheet.getRange('H2').getValue();
  var repmobile = spreadsheet.getRange('AA2').getValue();
  var repemail = spreadsheet.getRange('AB2').getValue();

     GmailApp.sendEmail({
        to: clientemail,
        subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
        htmlBody: createEmailBody(clientname, repname, repmobile, repemail),
        name: 'myname', 
        from: 'welcome@mydoamin.com', 
        replyTo: repemail
      });
```

---

Thanks to the great help from you guys, I have now changed the code to:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail({
    recipient: clientemail, 
    subject: email_subject, 
    htmlBody: createEmailBody(clientname.toString(), repname.toString(), repmobile.toString(), repemail.toString()),
    {name: 'myname',
    from: 'welcome@mydomain.com', 
    replyTo: repemail}
  });
```

Now the error is:

> Invalid property ID

on the line which starts with "{name"

Comment: It could be because your parameters are incorrect. I didn't check it though. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) I think you want to use `MailApp`. You are using `MailApp`'s signature here. `GmailApp` has different signature

Comment: Thanks! I'm using GmailApp just because of its ability to change the "from" to one of my aliases. As far as I understood, MailApp cannot do this.

Comment: Yeah. Does it work after fixing the parameters?

Comment: No, it didn't work :(

Comment: Consider updating your question with correct parameters. You might want to keep it as simple as possible for the time being.

Comment: parameters are values from the spreadsheet

Comment: Please, check reference docs - call signature does not match docs. `sendEmail` should have: `recipient, subject, body, options`. The error message is clear on that: there is no such method that can be called with a single object as parameter. Fix that and you are good to go :) Btw, Madhurjya's suggestions was to fix the *signature*, not the parameters *themselves*

Comment: @user13708028 You don't have to write `recipient` , `subject`. You just write them straight without specifying. Only `advanced parameters` like `htmlBody` and others are explicitly specified within curly braces `{ }`. See my second example properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You are not using the [sendEmail method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) correctly as you are passing an object as a single parameter instead of the right parameters. According to the documentation linked above, your parameters should be the following:

- recipient (String)
- Subject (String)
- Body (String)
- Options (Object)

Therefore, your method would eventually be like this:

```js
GmailApp.sendEmail(clientemail, email_subject,createEmailBody(clientname.toString(), repname.toString(), repmobile.toString(), repemail.toString()),{
    name: 'myname',
    from: 'welcome@mydomain.com', 
    replyTo: repemail}
  );
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Answer (score 1):

Modify this code for your requirements.

Code is copied from Official documentation. The correct way to do this is:

```
function myFunction() {
// The code below will send an email with the current date and time.
var now = new Date();
GmailApp.sendEmail("email@example.com", "current time", "The time is: " + now.toString()); 
}
```

---

Edit: HTML body sample as requested:

```
function myFunction() {
// The code below will send an email with the current date and time.
var now = new Date();
GmailApp.sendEmail("email@example.com", "current time", "The time is: " + now.toString(),{htmlBody: '<h1>hello</h1>'});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use the htmlBody? I cannot use it with the parameters I listed?

Comment: Updated. Check it now

Comment: I'll take a step back. I'm basing my code on this example [link](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/content-signup)

Comment: Okay. So what are your requirements? That looks like a very well written post.

Comment: What do you mean by requirements? It's simply not working :(

Comment: If you have changed the email address in the code that I have pasted, it is bound to work in Apps Script. If you are doing it from within spreadsheet, there are probably other things to be done as well. And that/those would be another question (s)

Comment: @user13708028 - show what you've changed (it is never as simple as "not working" - please, be specific what exactly is wrong, what is expected, etc). Please, do not override the original quetion, append the change to it (no need for "Edit" / "Update" title - you can separate sections with `---` [three dashes])

Comment: @Oleg Valter thanks! I've updated as you suggested and now face a new error, as detailed in my edit of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a supplementary answer:

you need to learn to understand the error messages - they are your best friends when debugging, but they are not always intuitive. In your case the error states: *Cannot find method sendEmail(object)*. Try to parse it as you would a template string, the message says:

1. Cannot *find method*
2. Method searched is `sendEmail`
3. It is passed an instance of `object` as a single argument

Since there is obviously a method called `sendEmail` (after making sure there are no typos), you can safely eliminate first two parts. That leaves us with the "instance of object" - a natural question then would be "is it allowed to pass an object to this method?". If you look at the docs, it is not.

But you could avoid all of this in the first place. There is an blog post I find very useful - [6 deadly sins](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2017/12/07/6-deadly-sins-google-apps-script-add-on/) of GAS Add-on development. The first one strikes an apple - you will be much better off not using the script editor and install an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) or editor that supports autocomplete (be it VS Code, Netbeans or others).

That being said, repeating the other answers, the method signature is structured this way:

```
 sendEmail( recipient, subject,  body,   options )
________________________________________________
  name        arg0       arg1    arg2    [arg3]
```

Note that the first three arguments are *mandatory* and only the fourth one is *optional*.
If you look at reference docs again, `options` is where all of the *advanced* parameters reside.

**Notes**

1. On curly brackets: I assume you know this, but just in case: this is an object literal (initializer) [notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) that is used to instantiate an object. You don't have to wrap all of parameters in a single object if a method signature says otherwise (I think you are on the right track, though - it is good to declare your APIs with a single config parameter, just don't violate the public contract).

**References**

1. `sendEmail` with options [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
2. `sendEmail` without options [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)
3. `MailApp` method `sendEmail` [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)